# CVC4 minimize/maximize model optimization

Tags: optimization, z3, smt, cvc4

Does CVC4 an option to maximize or minimize the result model for bitvectors [as Z3 does](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Opt/tutorial/guide)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, CVC4 does not (yet) support optimization.  For bitvectors, you can always do it yourself using multiple queries and binary search, but it's not built-in.